# How to use Contacts Framework to fetch selected contact number

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios9

I am using AddressBook framework to fetch selected contact number but it is not working in iPad, Then I come to know that AddressBook Framework is deprecated in iOS 9, Now I want to use Contacts Framework but I am not able to find anything related to contacts Framework in objective C. if any one knows how to use contact framework please answer me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about Contacts Framework in Apple's official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/

The samples seem to be available only in Swift, but class references are available for Objective-C as well.